# How could I use the spark-operator-k8s to listen to a Q in RabbitMQ and then trigger spark jobs with the amqp message as job arguments?

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

am having a `spark-operator-k8s` which am able to run using kubectl commands. But now I want to use that as a consumer for rabbitmq. Also suggestions are welcome for this approach and I would like to understand if there are better ways to do achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are planning to comment; how I solved the above!

We use [spark-k8s-operator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator) to manage the spark applications in k8s
and turns out spark-k8s-operator was not designed to listen any `amqp` messages and so in order to trigger spark-k8s-operators to trigger a `spark-submit` command, from within the celery worker pod we generate the manifest for the sparkApplication on the dynamically and then call the [kubernetes REST API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.13/#-strong-api-overview-strong-) with the manifest.

In order to manually trigger the same using `kubectl` one could write their the sparkApplication manifest and run `kubectl apply -f <manifest.yml>`